# Can I assign while desconstructing?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

For example:

```
const obj = {name: 'jack', age: 18, gender: 'male'}
const {name, age} = obj
const obj2 = {name, age}
```

I want some key-value of a obj to make up a new obj, above is three line codes , I want to know if there is a way more concise? in one line?

Comment: `const obj2 = {name: 'jack', age: 18}`?

Comment: I am not sure why you would do that, but... const obj2 = { name, age } = { name: 'jack', age: 18, gender: 'male' };

Comment: @Zunino In a react framework i need to pick up some props from a bigger object, it can't work, `obj2` will has both the three props

Comment: @Zunino No, that does not work: it assign the original object to `obj2`, and it does assign to global variables.

Comment: @Bergi You're right. As for the original question, I couldn't come up with anything that wouldn't look cumbersome and worse than the original code. For instance, take a look at this monstrosity: Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).filter(e => ["name", "age"].includes(e[0]))) --not to mention there is no support for Object.fromEntries yet. I'm out of ideas for now. Sorry.

Comment: @Zunino See the second duplicate link